# Capybara javascript specs consume too much memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, capybara, circleci

I am working on automated test builds using CircleCI, utilizing Capybara to write feature specs in rails.

The issue is that it seems like any time we write specs using the `js: true` flag, they consume too much memory and cause us to hit the 4gb limit on circleci containers.

I enabled SSH on a debug build, ran the top program, and checked what was using the most memory. It is by far the ruby process, which ends up consuming over 3.5gb of memory. This only happens in builds with javascript enabled specs.

I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before or has any ideas for reducing the memory footprint of these specs.

I have noticed that if I run the entire spec suite locally, it opens a new chrome window for each feature spec, and never closes them until the entire test run is finished.

Running `rspec spec --profile 10` locally also shows our only two js specs in the top 10 slowest specs, with one of them being the #1 slowest, taking over 10 seconds. It's a fairly short spec, too, it logs someone in and clicks a couple of things.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  config.around(:each, :run_jobs_inline => true) do |example|
    Resque.inline = true
    example.run
    Resque.inline = false
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongo_mapper].strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DeferredGarbageCollection.start
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DeferredGarbageCollection.reconsider
  end


  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    Rails.cache.clear
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Timecop.return
  end

  config.filter_run_excluding :ignore => true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome

Capybara.register_driver :iphone do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {browser: :chrome, switches: %w[--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ (iPhone;\ CPU\ iPhone\ OS 5_0\ like\ Mac\ OS\ X)\ AppleWebKit/534.46\ (KHTML,\ like\ Gecko)\ Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3]})
end

[:iphone, :chrome].each do |capybara_driver|
  Capybara::Screenshot.register_driver(capybara_driver) do |driver, path|
    driver.browser.save_screenshot(path)
  end
end
```

Comment: JS specs are going to be slower than non JS specs because they open a browser and then have a lot more communications overhead as well as the time it takes a browser to do things.  That said, if your specs are opening a new chrome window for every test you have something configured wrong, since by default it reuses the same window, add your Capybara (and rspec or whatever test framework you're using) configuration to your question.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Done. I'm using the transactional_capybara gem, which is why I am able to use transactional fixtures in this config.

Comment: Sharing the DB connection has too many edge cases/limitations in Rails <= 5.0 (possibly fixed in Rails 5.1) to be worth it (and the wait for ajax stuff at the end isn't doing anything since around Capybara 2.7) so transactional_capybara is just a bad idea, although it wouldn't be causing one window per test.  You should also be using `append_after` instead of `after` for the block that calls `DatabaseCleaner.clean` since it needs to be the last thing run -  Are you creating Capybara sessions manually, or using the default automatic session management?

Comment: Something else to try would be commenting out your GC disabling and seeing how that affects the memory usage.

Comment: I don't think I'm creating Capybara sessions manually, so I would assume that I'm not. Would that be something I would have to do intentionally within each spec? I'm not sure what that would look like or how to do it. I will try out your suggestions and see how it impacts performance.

Comment: If you were creating sessions manually you would have code like `session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome, app)` around.  None of the code you've posted would create a new window per test though, are you sure you don't have any other RSpec before/after/configure blocks?  If not (and your tests aren't opening new windows and not closing them) maybe post the code of one of the tests.

Comment: After some more research, I think it's only opening 1 chrome browser for each driver. As you can see in my config, I have a chrome driver and an iphone driver, for testing mobile vs non-mobile. It appears to open and maintain 1 browser for each driver, which does make sense, I think. I wonder if this one additional browser is enough to push my run over the edge. It could be it's not an issue with feature specs, but the entire spec suite, and the features are just the straw breaking the camels back.

Comment: Correct, 1 chrome browser instance per driver would be expected

Comment: If it is just the size of your app and the need for running two Chrome instances, one potential solution to your memory issues may be to break your tests into two tasks, one that runs the non-JS tests and one that runs the JS tests

Comment: This did end up being do the custom deferred garbage collection we were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run tests in parallel? Meaning, it simply start separate thread of your app, and if you run it in parallel, it can create too many threads in the same time and use too much memory.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/JI6JrirL9gM/R6YiXj4gi_UJ

It's assumption, of course.